# Right align nav-pills drop down menu

Tags: alignment, dropdown, nav-pills

I am trying to align my drop down menu along the right side. Please see the attached picture and reference HTML code. Only a float right has been applied via CSS to move the drop down to the right side of the screen.

[image: Drop down alignment]

```
<li class="dropdown" id="it"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">IT Tools
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="drop">
                        <li><a href="/printers/index.html">Printer Info</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://rciessweb1.ricoh.ca/EService">Ricoh Support</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://printserver2k8:9191/admin">Paper Cut</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://nagios/nagiosxi/">Nagios</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply added dropdown-menu-right in this bit:

`<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">`

It worked for me!